# Identify the first occurrenc of a column value in pyspark and then increment another column based on it

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to increment a column when i encounter a new customer id in pyspark
My pyspark dataframe (type - pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame) has 2 columns
Customer_id
101
101
102
103
103
103
Whenever a new Customer_ID the flag value is reset to 1 and increment when the same id is encountered. I want the following output dataframe
Customer_id            Flag

101                       1

101                  2

102          1

103          1

103          2

103          3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window` clause **`row_number()`** function with `partitionBy` on `customer_id` column

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy("customer_id").orderBy(lit("1"))
df1=df.withColumn("Flag",row_number().over(w))
df1.show()
#+-----------+----+
#|customer_id|Flag|
#+-----------+----+
#|        101|   1|
#|        101|   2|
#|        102|   1|
#|        103|   1|
#|        103|   2|
#|        103|   3|
#+-----------+----+
```

Comment: Can i store this is a pyspark dataframe? I tried type(df1) but it is giving Type:NoneType

Comment: @shreeja7, Yes.. Try `df1=df.withColumn("Flag",row_number().over(w))`